# How to change the time period for selected processes only using asyncio?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I have the following code that executes a list of methods (_tick_watchers) every 10 seconds. While this is fine for most of the methods on the _tick_watchers list, there are some that I need to be executed only once every 5 minutes. Any ideas for a simple & neat way to do so?

```
async def on_tick(self):
    while not self._exiting:
        await asyncio.sleep(10)

        now = time.time()

        # call all tick watchers
        for w in self._tick_watchers:
            w(now)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some class for periodic execution? If so, you can add timeout parameter to it.

timeout in init:

```
def __init__(self, timeout=10):
    self.timeout = timeout
```

and use it in tick handler:

```
async def on_tick(self):
    while not self._exiting:
        await asyncio.sleep(self.timeout)
        # ...
```

Then create and run several instances of that class with different timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

Since `asyncio` doesn't come with a scheduler for repeating tasks, you can generalise your `on_tick()` into one:

```
import time
import asyncio

class App:
    def my_func_1(self, now):
        print('every second\t{}'.format(now))

    def my_func_5(self, now):
        print('every 5 seconds\t{}'.format(now))

    def __init__(self):
        self.exiting = False

    async def scheduler(self, func, interval):
        while not self.exiting:
            now = time.time()
            func(now)
            await asyncio.sleep(interval)
            # to combat drift, you could try something like this:
            # await asyncio.sleep(interval + now - time.time()) 

    async def run(self):
        asyncio.ensure_future(self.scheduler(self.my_func_5, 5.0))
        asyncio.ensure_future(self.scheduler(self.my_func_1, 1.0))
        await asyncio.sleep(11)
        self.exiting = True

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(App().run())  # test run
```

Note that currently you do not start your task every 10 seconds: you wait for 10 seconds after the task exits. The small difference accumulates over time, which might be important.